# Modifying strings in emu8086 assembly

Tags: string, assembly

I currently working on an intro assignment for a computer architecture course and i was asked to accomplish some string modifications. My question is not how to do it, but what should i be researching to be able to do it? Is there any functions that will make this easier, for example .reverse() is java.

What i need to accomplish is getting string input from the user, reverse the letters (while reversing numbers keep them where they are), add spaces whenever there is a vowel, and alternate the caps.

Example:

```
 Input: AbC_DeF12 
 Output: f E d _ c B a 2 1
```

This is code i ripped from the lecture: http://pastebin.com/2E1UtGdD I put it in pastebin to avoid clutter. Anything used in this is fair game. (this code does have limitiations though, it only support ~9 characters and the looping doesn't work at the end of strings)

Comment: If you truly didn't put this question up to ask how to do it, then I would take down the majority of the question text. As it stands, until I read carefully, I thought someone had just copy and pasted their assignment.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Good point, editing it now.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Thank you, this will be a decent read. Hopefully i can take something i need from it.

Comment: I backed that comment out; I'm not sure those instructions are native 8086. Instead, [take a look at this](http://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_instruction_set.pdf)

Comment: I'd like confirmation of this, but I don't think that the 8086 has any knowledge of what a string is.. only bytes.

Comment: Usually there are no built-in functions to do that in native assembly, except (and even then maybe) I/O operations. You have to do everything yourself. Unless you have access to some libraries, of course. I don't know your exact requirements.

Comment: @m0skit0 I have updated my question to include code i ripped form the lecutre

Comment: @Kevin You should include the code here, not in an external pastebin link. That link will eventually expire and question will be again missing information.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at it like this.

Generate a function on paper of how you want to achieve this. This is notes and only a starting point.

```
Loop from 0 to string length.
if(byte >= 'A' || byte <= 'Z') then byte -= 'A' - 'a'; /* convert to lower case */
if(byte >= 'a' || byte <= 'z') then byte += 'A' - 'a'; /* convert to upper case */

/* Switch the letters only. */
a = 0; b = string length

Loop i from a to b. if((input >= 'A' && input <='Z') || (input >= 'a' && input <='z')) p = i
Loop j from b to a. if((input >= 'A' && input <='Z') || (input >= 'a' && input <='z')) q = j

c = input[i]; input[i] = input[j]; input[j] = c;

/* Regenerate the string and add spaces. */
loop i, 0 to string length
if(input[i] == 'A' 'a' 'E' 'e' ...) string2[j] = ' '; j++; string2[j] = input[i]; j++;
i++
```

After that if you don't know 8086 I would look at examples online of how to do each individual part. The most important bit is generating the code in your head and on paper on how it is going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know what i have to do, and how i have to do it, the thing i am stuck on is more just the syntax, and what i should be using to accomplish this.You did give me a couple of ideas though so thanks again.

Comment: @Kevin If you don't know the syntax go learn it. I don't know what you mean *"what I should be using to accomplish this"*. There's nothing more than assembly you should be using. Sorry but it looks like you're expecting us to code it for you, even if you said you don't. That is just not going to happen.